# Custom 401 page when Windows authentication fails using ASP.NET Core 6 Blazor on IIS / Kestrel

Tags: iis, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication, kestrel-http-server, unauthorized

I am using Blazor Server and would like to display content for unauthorized users to help them. Instead of the defined *NotAuthorized* content, I receive error messages from IIS / Kestrel.

**App.razor:**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized><div>Not authorized!</div></NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing><div>Authorizing ...</div></Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Normally it works fine using windows authentication for me using Edge. When I use a different browser or a private window and try to access the page, I get a login request. I can login fine using it, but if I cancel that, it is not working as expected. I expect to receive the content *Not authorized!* This does not happen though, I tried both IIS & Kestrel:

Using Kestrel I am getting the error 401 "This page isn't working right now"

Using IIS I am getting an error message generated by IIS (HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized).

Edit: If I enable both windowsAuthentication, as well as anonymousAuthentication in IIS, then I receive the same error Kestrel shows.

How can I configure a custom 401 page in Blazor to show when authentication fails?

Comment: There's a difference between authentication ("Who are you?") and authorization ("Are you allowed here?"). Authentication happens first. A 401 response is the normal and required first step for authentication. If you are ending with a 401 that means authentication has failed and you haven't even gotten to authorization.

Comment: To display a custom page when authentication fails, you need to change the body of the 401 response. I've done this in ASP.NET, but not in Blazor, so I can't really help there.

Answer (score 1):

Windows authentication happens long before HTTP requests go into ASP.NET Core processing, so when 401.1 (not 401.2) responses are sent back to the browsers, none of your ASP.NET Core side code is triggered yet.

> Though not the same, ASP.NET Core works similar to [ASP.NET on IIS 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis#aspnet-integration-architecture). So, ASP.NET Core events happen after many IIS events.

To display a better error page to your users who failed Windows authentication, you should customize IIS 401.1 error page.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Any idea how to solve this for Kestrel as well?